# Transaction inside transaction support? (multi database) in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions, multi-database

I have DB1, DB2. I config two `DataSource` and two `PlatformTransactionManager` for two database (within the same physical machine).
I have this code:

```java
@Transaction("DB1")
public void A() {
    B();
}
@Transaction("DB2")
public void B() {
}
```

When `B()` has an `SqlException`, data in DB1 did not rollback. How to implement rollback DB1?
Thank very much.

Comment: If these methods belong to the same class, then I would suggest to introduce 2 separate classes so that each of them to use only one data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Transaction annotation has an attribute `rollbackFor` (`@Transaction(value = "DB1", rollbackFor = SqlException.class)` for example) that may cover your needs.

However, there is only one transaction will be actually used in your code, because `B` is invoked not via Spring proxy but via inner call (`this.B()`). To execute method inside a separate transaction method must be invoked via Spring proxy - `someService.B()`, not `this.B()`.